# FSM enters impossible state

Tags: vhdl, vivado, fsm

I have a FSM consisting of 3 states: `STATIC`, `UP` and `DOWN`.

The FSM starts in the `STATIC` state and if I press the up arrow key, it will move to the `UP` state, thereafter returning to the `STATIC` state. Same thing for `DOWN`.

At first the FSM works well but suddenly after a random amount of key presses it will enter an unspecified state. The FSM consists of two processes:

```
type ALL_STATES is (STATIC, UP, DOWN);
signal STATE, NEXT_STATE: ALL_STATES;
signal posBarraYTOP, posBarraYBOT: std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
signal movTeclado: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

-- ...
Keybd: keyboard port map (input, movTeclado); -- keyboard output
-- ...

bar_FSM_sincrono: process(CLK, RST) -- CLK is the FPGA's clock
begin
    if RST='1' then
        STATE <= STATIC;
    elsif (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
        STATE <= NEXT_STATE; -- in each CLK cycle we move to the next state.
    end if;    
end process bar_FSM_sincrono;

bar_FSM_cambioest: process(STATE)
begin
    case STATE is
        when STATIC=> 
            seg <= "1001001";
            if (movTeclado = "01" and posBarraYTOP > 20) then
                NEXT_STATE <= UP;
            elsif (movTeclado = "10" and posBarraYBOT < 980) then
                NEXT_STATE <= DOWN;
            else
                NEXT_STATE <= STATIC;
            end if;
        when UP | DOWN =>
            NEXT_STATE <= STATIC;
            seg <= "1111110";
        when others =>
            NEXT_STATE <= STATIC;
            seg <= "0110111";
    end case;
end process bar_FSM_cambioest;
```

`movTeclado` is a 2-bit signal that shows when the user presses the up `01` or down `10` key. It's `00` if no key is pressed. movTeclado doesn't give me any problems.

`posBarraYTOP` and `posBarraYBOT` are two signals to describe a boundary, and these conditions are always met.

I use `seg` as a signal for the 7-segment display to debug and find out in what state the FSM is at. At first it always displays the `STATIC seg`, as it should since `UP seg` and `DOWN seg` are only displayed for one cycle. But then when the error happens it's when it starts displaying the `others seg`, as well as the `STATIC seg`. It's a back-and-forth between `STATIC` and `others`, which I don't understand since when `STATE = STATIC`, it should only transition to `UP` or `DOWN`.

Thank you for reading this far, does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Please can you post the full code? If `STATE` is an enumerated unresolved type then based on your code it should not compile at all because `STATE` has multiple drivers.

Comment: @Tricky Sorry! I've added the signals declarations on top.

Comment: So yes, my comment is valid - `STATE` has multiple drivers and shouldnt even get past a syntax check.

Comment: I don't really understand, isn't `STATE` supposed to be one of the three possible states: `STATIC`, `UP` or `DOWN`? Also, the code compiles in VIVADO 2021.2 (thus why I found that FSM error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other comments have suggested, you should never drive a signal from more than one `process` block. Personally I don't like writing state machines like this, with 2 process blocks, because I find it confusing.

But regardless, your 2nd process block (the combinational one) should only be assigning `NEXT_STATE`, it should never make an assignment to `STATE` since that's taken care of by the first process block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm really sorry but I made a mistake and instead of `STATE` in the combinational block it should say `NEXT_STATE`. (I translated it and made that typo). Again, I apologize for the mistake. I'll fix it right now.

As for the first comment, you mean how I use the `NEXT_STATE` signal between the two processes?

Comment: For a single process state machine, simply delete the `NEXT_STATE` signal and process, and simply do all the state transitioning directly in the `bar_FSM_sincrono` process and assign directly to `STATE`. This would also force you to register your outputs.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your bar_FSM_cambioest sensitivity list is incomplete.  It needs to include all signals who's changes will affect the process's output.

```
bar_FSM_cambioest: process(STATE, movTeclado, posBarraYTOP, posBarraYBOT)
```

My next question would be how fast is your clock?  Are you trying to go from the STATIC segment display to the UP/DOWN one and back faster than the 7-segment display can reliably update?